# Promotheus metrics for Robot Framework exist?

Tags: selenium, testing, junit, robotframework, prometheus

Is there any support for promotheus metrics (RED) for Robot Framework or robot based test cases .

```
global:
scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.



# Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Robot Framework?

Comment: i am doing testing using selenium on robot framework and need to find the metrics as RED in promotheus @LaurencevdWel